# Как определить исключение «число не является вещественным» в Си?

Tags: c

В файле txt необходимо узнать кол-во вещественных чисел, *записанных через пробел*. Подразумевается, что там должны быть только вещественные числа (данные с датчика). В случае если там оказывается слово, целочисленное, неверная запись, как определить это ? Вот код подсчёта:

````
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    FILE* file;
    float num;
    int index = 0;

    file = fopen("C:/Users/.../input.txt", "a+");
    if (file  == NULL)
    {
        printf("Ошибка! Недопустимый объект гиперссылки\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
       
        while (fscanf(file, "%f", &num) == true) {
            printf("%f\n", num);
            index++;
        }
      
        fprintf(file, "\nКол-во: %d", index);
        fclose(file);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Не правильно. Целые числа будут успешно читаться (также как и действительные). При попытке ввода не числа цикл завершится.

Comment: Здесь нет исключений. В вопросе я прошу подсказать, как их создать.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду `exception` (как в C++ или Java)? Если да, то на уровне языка никак. В Си нет понятия exception (наиболее близкое это послать сигнал самому себе (в \*nix) или м.б. вызвать longjmp (но почти наверняка вы это не имели в виду)

Comment: @DredWolf, посмотрите ответ. Если он совсем ни в какие ворота не лезет, я переделаю на чтение слов и их анализ.

Answer (score 2):

`fscanf` возвращает число прочитанных и присвоеных значений. Не нужно сравнивать  его результат с `true`.

В вашем случае читать числа нужно по одному. Если число не прочитано - значит вы встретили слово или неверный формат. При этом fscanf может не продвинуться по файлу вперёд. Чтобы продвинутся, можно пропустить символы до пробела с помощью `fscanf(f, "%*s")`. Это чтение без присвоения, мы просто пропускаем хвост неправильного "слова".

`fscanf` так же может вернуть `FEOF`. В примере ниже я этого не проверяю, так как есть проверка `feof` в заголовке цикла. В более сложных случаях проверять нужно отдельно: "неправильный формат" и "конец файла" - это две разные ошибки, которые часто надо обрабатывать по разному.

Ещё одно, не такое ужасное: не работайте с `float` без веских причин, только `double`.

Вот пример:

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 fscanf_filtering.c
#include <stdio.h>

void scan(FILE *f) {
    while (!feof(f)) {
        double n;
        if (fscanf(f, "%lf", &n) == 1) {
            printf("number %lf\n", n);
        } else {
            printf("failure\n");
            fscanf(f, "%*s");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    scan(stdin);
}
```

А это результат для текста `1.23 1.23e2 word 345 34a48e16 15 df`. Обратите внимание на число `34`. Не уверен что вы хотите его прочитать:

```
number 1.230000
number 123.000000
failure
number 345.000000
number 34.000000
failure
number 15.000000
failure
failure
```

Comment: Читать надо по формату `%s`  (у TC в условии целое число это тоже ошибка) и анализировать прочитанные символы (можно strtod/strtol)

Comment: Это кажется неплохим решением, если вы будете контролировать переполнение из-за длинных строк. Текущий вариант хотя бы безопасен в этом отношении. Хотя и не идеален.

Comment: Я не очень доверяю TC в постановке задачи. Полагаю что на деле целые числа для него годятся.

Comment: На это сможет ответить только преподаватель, который дал ему такое задание

Comment: Спасибо, очень хороший ответ. Попытался адаптировать под себя. Почему при нахождении исключения не записывается "Ошибка" в конец файла? Как это реализовать?
`while (!feof(file)) {
if (fscanf(file, "%lf", &n) == 1) {
printf("number %lf\n", n);
}
else {
fprintf(file,"\nОшибка\n");
break;
}
}`
Извините, почему-то слетает форматирование кода в коментариях :(

Comment: Вы пишете в файл открытый для чтения. Так не сработает. Нужно всё прочитать, запомнить была ли ошибка, закрыть файл, открыть в режиме `append` и записать всё что вы хотите.